# Set up background for all pages / specific pages in Context

Tags: context, backgrounds

I'm trying to put a background image on all pages across a Context document, but adding `repeat=yes` to `\definelayer` and `state=repeat` to `\setupbackgrounds` doesn't seem to work.

I'd also like to know whether I can turn on/off the defined background in the middle of the text.

```
\setupcolors[state=start]

\setuppagenumbering[state=stop]

\definelayer[mybg]  % name of the layer
    [repeat=yes % all pages of the document
    x=0mm, y=0mm,  % from upper left corner of paper
     width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight, % let the layer cover the full paper
     repeat=yes
     ] 

\setlayer[mybg] % name of the layer
    %[hoffset=1cm, voffset=1cm]  % placement (from upper left corner of the layer)
    {\externalfigure[cow][width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]}  % the actual contents of the layer

\setupbackgrounds[page][background=mybg,state=repeat % repeat each page
]

\setupindenting[yes,small]


\starttext

asdf
\page
asdf
\page
asdf

\stoptext
```

Comment: You've missed a comma after `repeat=yes`. You could use `\setupbackgrounds[page][background=<newbackground>]` and `\setupbackgrounds[page][background=<oldbackground>]` when needed.

Comment: Just that? I guess I'd never haver figured that out. But do I need a comma after all last arguments (there's no comma after `state=repeat`) or just in this particular case? Anyways, if you turn your comment into an answer I'll accept it, thanks a lot.

Comment: I meant, you wrote `repeat=yes` twice in `\definelayer` and the first instance lacks a comma so it's possibly the reason your example didn't work.

Comment: Now I see. It's weird because I put a comma in the last and one it worked, too.

Comment: @JairoA.delRio: Could you please post your comment as an answer

Comment: @Aditya Yeah, no problem. Give me a minute, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub><sup>This answer is mainly for eventual ConTeXt users with the same question in case a comment answer isn't clear enough.</sup></sub>

You missed a comma in your layer definition. To answer your actual question, it's as easy as applying your background after `\page`. Even better, using `\setups`es makes the task less cumbersome. Below an example:

```
%For testing only
\usecolors[svg]
\setuppapersize[A7]
\setupexternalfigure[location=default]
%
\definelayer[firsttest][repeat=yes,width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]
\setlayer[firsttest]{\externalfigure[spider][width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]}
\definelayer[secondtest][repeat=yes,width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]
\setlayer[secondtest]{\externalfigure[hacker][width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]}
%Setups for abbreviating
\startsetups Background:firsttest
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=firsttest]
\stopsetups
%
\startsetups Background:secondtest
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=secondtest]
\stopsetups
%Let's see if color backgrounds work
\startsetups Background:thirdtest
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=color,backgroundcolor=gold]
\stopsetups
%
\starttext
%Spider
\setups[Background:firsttest]
\dorecurse{2}{\input bryson}
\page
%Color
%It works fine without a "repeat" specification
\setups[Background:thirdtest]
\input knuth
\page
%Hacker
%You're able to reuse backgrounds ad libitum
%\setups[Background:firsttest]
\setups[Background:secondtest]
\dorecurse{2}{\input tufte}
\page
\stoptext
```

[image]